# Drupal automating file uploads without access to API or ability to install modules

Tags: drupal

At work, I'm working on a large web migration.  I am trying to figure out a way to upload a large amount of PDF files to the Drupal platform we're migrating to.  As the title says, the client has not given us access to the API or any mass upload modules.  So I have to upload all 1,200 PDF files in the same fashion as an end-user; point, click, fill the form, publish, confirm publish...hours and hours and hours of work that should take 5 minutes.

My only option seems to be automating the process with a web automation tool or a script with HTTP requests.

I've written a script that's automated logging in and navigating to the download creation page, I cannot seem to actually accomplish the selection of the file I'm trying to upload. The element looks like this:

```
<input type="file" id="edit-upload" name="files[upload]" size="60" class="form-file">
```

Even if I automate the process with the Firefox Selenium plug-in, once the recording actually gets to the "Choose File" portion, it cannot figure out how to actually populate the field with the file.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to get around this?

My preferred language is Python, I'm not sure if that's actually ending up being a limitation since Drupal is PHP based.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of uncooperative clients, but not allowing server or Drupal admin access? Yikes!

Perhaps Selenium Server plus its Python bindings would allow you to script the upload of your 1200 files.